# Hair Particle Removing System

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, particles

Hi I was watching this tutotrial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SzbuZTlMGPE&t=339s and wanted to make something simiallr. However this only works for parctiles that are emitted and not the hair settings. Is there anyway to get the same effect without changing settings? Essencially I'm making animation where a skull rolls accross a field and kills the grass at it touches it. Here's a picture for better understanding as to why I can't change to emitter. [image]

Comment: You could try using dynamic paint weighting on the hair to control their size or possibly they colour to look like its shriveling up or disappearing.